# Error in intercepting the request of an Android application

Tags: man-in-the-middle, android, burp-suite, tls-intercept

I'm trying to analyze my flutter app's network traffic so I used burp suite for intercepting. First, I'm using the proxy option of burpsuite. I set my PC's IP address and port as 8080. Also in my Android device I set the proxy in WiFi with hostname as my PC IP address and port as 8080. Then I also installed the certificate from IP_address:8080. But still it doesn't capture any request of that app. But it can intercept some inbuilt apps.

What's the reason and what's the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Not all Android apps respect the global/systemwide proxy settings, especially when running Android 7 or higher. It looks like you used a [regular proxy](https://docs.mitmproxy.org/stable/concepts-modes/#regular-proxy) but that might not work. You could try [transparent proxies](https://docs.mitmproxy.org/stable/concepts-modes/#transparent-proxy) but that's considerably more difficult and might require rooting your device. I tried to do that a while ago in order to analyze the traffic of the official Stack Exchange Android app, but failed to do so because it's HTTPS traffic; instead, I choose to run it on an old device running Android 5.1.

Comment: Is there some other ways for analysing the network traffic of my app?

Comment: Using a transparent proxy probably works (it didn't for me because of HTTPS and not wanting to root the device).